# How does the latin root of "egregious" relate to its English definition?

Tags: latin, roots

The latin root of the word `egregious` is `grex` meaning `flock` which is also the [root of many other English words that deal with groups](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/grex) or "flocks" (usually of people): aggregate, congregate, segregate, gregarious...

But I don't see how the definition of egregious has anything to do with a flock or group.

**egregious**
[ih-gree-juh s] *adjective*

1. extraordinary in some bad way; glaring; flagrant: an egregious
   mistake; an egregious liar.
2. Archaic. distinguished or eminent.

Comment: If you are e (ex) anything, you are out of it: if you are outside the flock, you stand out. Like an egregious mistooken. Hm.

Comment: @Lambie yeah makes sense. I didn't realize that the "e" part of the word implied "ex".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> #### Egregious (adj)
>
> - 1530s, "distinguished, eminent, excellent," from Latin egregius "distinguished, excellent, extraordinary," from the phrase ex grege "rising above the flock," from ex "out of" (see ex-) + grege, ablative of grex "a herd, flock"

Disapproving sense, now predominant, arose late 16c., originally ironic. It is not in the Latin word, which etymologically means simply "exceptional."

([Etymon](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=egregious))

Comment: tall poppies come to mind...

Comment: the OED retains egregious with a positive sense of exceptionality.